# String Array index not holding null value

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, openxml-sdk

I have a string array, but null values are not indexed and stored

For example, if I have an array { "one", "", "three" }, value of array[0] is one and value of array[1] becomes three instead of "", why is null values removed and index of next value becomes the null value.

Here is my code, I am using Open XML SDK to read and store excel cells into an array.

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
        int i = 0;
        string[] rowData = new string[9];
        var cells = row.Elements<Cell>();

        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            if (cell != null)
            {
                var index = Int32.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text);

                if (cell.DataType != null)
                {
                    rowData[i] = GetSharedStringItemById(workbookPart, index);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        var store = new UserStore<User>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<User>(store);
        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = rowData[0],
            FirstName = rowData[1],
            LastName = rowData[2],
            Email = rowData[3],
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            RegisterdOn = now,
            Employer = new Employer()
            {
                CompanyName = rowData[4],
                AddressLine1 = rowData[5],
                AddressLine2 = rowData[6],
                City = rowData[7],  <---if value of city is null, the value of PostCode is used?
                PostCode = rowData[8],
            }
        };

        var result = manager.Create(user, "123456");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Employer");
        }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you posted, the problem is either that the `cell.CellValue.Text` property is returning the wrong index, or the `GetSharedStringItemById()` method is misusing the index that's passed to it. But your code example is woefully inadequate. If you want an actual answer, please post [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score -3):

You can check the below, if it helps

// check if the value of cell is null before converting  to integer

```
if(cell.CellValue.Text != null){

var index = Int32.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text);
```

// add the value of conversion to array

```
rowData[i] = GetSharedStringItemById(workbookPart, index);

  } 

//in case the value contained in a cell is null, then assign either "" or null 

rowData[i] = "";
```

Also, note that "" is not the same as null. if you test "" and null for equality, the  result of the test would be false.